# Meaning of "win convert(s)" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In my [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA9-PR97&lpg=RA9-PR97&dq=1100%20week%2031%20day%202&source=bl&ots=ErLVVDEXOH&sig=VCI2W4a9tpGeyRVNItnES645tY4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid9pP43p_NAhWMDpoKHecuAAAQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=1100%20week%2031%20day%202&f=false) you can see:

> In a free society it is intrinsic that individuals and groups have the inherent right to propagate ideas and try to **win converts**.

I can understand or guess that the author wants to point out that *in a free society people can change their religions readily*. But, I am not sure about the exact meaning or technical definition of the phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *convert* (noun) is a person who *converts* (intransitive verb) or *is converted* (transitive verb) from one affiliation—religious or political  or intellectual—to another.

To *win converts*, then, is to succeed in attracting *converts* to your affiliation.

What the author is writing about is not freedom to choose your own affiliation but "freedom of speech": freedom to attempt to persuade others to convert to your affiliation.

Comment: If it was a reading comprehension test, I assure you that I would choose the wrong option! Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, the verb *win* implies that you really had to struggle to convince others to join your side, or agree with your opinions, beliefs, religion etc. It is much like a **battle** of words and ideas. And in battles, there are *winners* and *losers*. Winners win. What do they win? **Converts**.

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to say how the metaphor works there.

Is the idea of (religious) **convert**  secularized, or are secular **ideas** being treated figuratively as religious tenets?